# Looking for non-polynomial functions subject to the constraint of either $f^{(i)}>b_i$ for some $i$

Tags: functions, special-functions

I've been working on a programming project where the most immediate solution to a problem is to fit a quadratic to the data. However, this doesn't completely work for the data since sometimes there are regions which essentially have increased or decreased slopes than what would be expected from a standard quadratic. An example of such a function one would like to fit can be seen in the following figure:
[image: Example Function]

(Note: I quickly made this plot as a composition of 3 quadratic functions with differing slopes, what would've been more optimal representation would be if there were no kinks at $x=-2$ and $2$)

Although one can not to difficultly solve for individual cases, this problem motivated a more general question of mine which I cannot think up a solution for.

> Does there exist a smooth function $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that:
>
> 1. $f^{(n)}=0 \ \forall n>k$
> 2. $f^{(i)}> b_i, \ b_i \in \mathbb R$ $\forall i \in I, \ I \subset \{1, \dots, k\}$
> 3. $f \neq \sum_{j=0}^{k}a_jx^j$

**Edit:** I overlooked the fact that 1 & 3 together imply a contradiction. Thus I'd like to alter my question to finding examples of functions where 2 & 3 are at play.

Reference recommendations, examples or a description of such a function in its generality would all be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If there is an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f^{(n)}(x) \equiv 0$ then $f$ is a polynomial. Why? Integrating a polynomial (in our case the zero function) gives a polynomial

Comment: You might want to look at _splines_: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there can't be, because your first and third assumption do not work together.

If you derive a function once and get zero then the function must have been constant. If you do it twice, you get that the function had to have been a linear function and so on. So you will always get a polynomial.

Moreover your plot seems to have a kink in it, so searching for a n times differentiale function to fit this, might not be a good idea.

Comment: Understood thanks. What about if we just have the 2nd and 3rd constraints?

Comment: Actually I am not so sure, what you want to do, with the second assumption.  Are the $b_i$ given in advance, or du you just mean that the derivatives have to be bounded? (If so, do you mean bounded in both directions? Or as it is written only towards $-\infty$)

Comment: Yes, the interpretation in your second comment was what was intended - a lower bound on i'th derivative everywhere. Also my intention was also for the $b_i$'s to be known beforehand. (Also, I clarified that the kink was unintended just below the plot). Thanks!

Comment: Well in that case, I think, for every set $\{b_i\}$ there should be infinitly such functions. But I do not think, that you are searching for those.... (you could generate one for example using the exponential function in combination with polynomials).  However, if you have enough datapoints, than you could consider fitting with a quadratic spline with sufficiant differentiability at the conections.